# get the values on the row with checked checkbox

Tags: apex, visualforce

How can I get the values on a pageblocktable with a checked checkbox on the side like this? 
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Action support.

Onclick of checkbox call a method and assign student record id to any variable

And in controller method iterate over the list and check which selected Id and student Id if matched. Means you have selected that row.

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!student.IsActive__c}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick"
                        action="{!handlestudentCheckboxChange}"
                        reRender="ResultPanel">
        <apex:param id="student" name="studentId" value="{!student.Id}"
                    assignTo="{!objSelectedStudentId}"/>
    </apex:actionSupport>
</apex:inputCheckbox>
```

Controller

```
public Id objSelectedStudentId {get;set;}

public void handlestudentCheckboxChange()
{
    for(Student__c objStudent: lstStudent)
    {
       if(objStudent.Id == objSelectedStudentId)
       {
          system.debug('-----This is the selected student record----'+objStudent);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: @gelay is this issue resolved.

Comment: no, the message is not showing.. i used  apexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(Apexpages.severity.error, teacher));

Comment: @gelay Sorry I can't see in your question you have asked anything related to `apexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(Apexpages.severity.error, teacher)); `

Comment: @gelay what is the issue you are facing. Let me know if I can help you.

Comment: i mean, sample, if the student is in the objSelectedStudentId, there will be displayed a message on the VFP. i used apePages.addmessage but it is not showing.

Comment: @gelay, you may need to rerender whatever block contains those `apex:pageMessages` as well in your `apex:actionSupport`, e.g. `rerender="ResultPanel,Messages"`

Comment: this has already been closed.